# Equivalent matlab function mod in numpy or python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, floating-point

I was converting some codes from Matlab to Python.

In matlab there is the function `mod` which gives the modulo operation.

For example the following example shows different results between the matlab `mod` and the equivalent numpy `remainder` operation:

Matlab:

```
>> mod(6, 0.05)

ans =

     0
```

Numpy:

```
np.remainder(6, 0.05) 
0.04999999999999967

np.mod(6, 0.05)
0.04999999999999967
```

Python modulus operator gives the same results as numpy.

```
6%0.05
0.04999999999999967
```

Is there anything in python which gives the same mod operation as the one in Matlab? preferably can be operated on `numpy` 2d/3d arrays.

`numpy` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.remainder.html) says that `numpy.mod` is equivalent to matlab `mod`.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.remainder.html), this computes the remainder complementary to the `floor_divide` function.
`np.floor_divide(6, 0.05)=119.0`. The value of `119.0*.05=5.95`. Thus, the value of remainder you get is `0.04999999999999967`.

Comment: @Aditya but shouldn't `6//0.05 == 120`.

Comment: `6//0.05 == 119.0`. It is rounding the number to the lower value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the core of the problem, in python:

```python
>>> 6/0.05 == 120
True

>>> 6//0.05 == 120  # this is 119 instead
False
```

The floating-point result of `6/0.05` is close enough to 120 (i.e. within the resolution of double precision) that it gets rounded to 120.0. However, it's ever so slightly smaller than 120, so explicit floor division will truncate that number to 119 before it could be normalized to 120.0.

Some proof:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
... print(6/Decimal(0.05))  # exactly approximate
... print(6/Decimal('0.05'))  # exact
119.9999999999999933386618522
1.2E+2
```

The first number is what you'd first get with `6/0.05`, but the number `119.9999999999999933386618522` gets rounded to the nearest number representable with double precision, and this is 120. One can easily prove that these two numbers are indeed the same within double precision:

```
>>> print(6/Decimal('0.05') - 6/Decimal(0.05))
6.6613381478E-15

>>> 120 - 6.6613381478E-15 == 120
True
```

Now here's `help mod` from MATLAB:

```
    MOD(x,y) returns x - floor(x./y).*y if y ~= 0, carefully computed to
    avoid rounding error. If y is not an integer and the quotient x./y is
    within roundoff error of an integer, then n is that integer.
```

This suggests that when `x/y` is close to an integer then it's rounded first, rather than being truncated like in python. So MATLAB goes out of its way to do some magic with the floating-point results.

The simplest solution would be to round your numbers yourself (unless you can use something like `decimal.Decimal`, but this means you should forgo native doubles entirely, including literals) and reproduce MATLAB's `mod` that way, assuming that makes sense for your use cases.

Comment: Thanks, I went by your suggestion and rounded the numbers myself. `np.round(6/array, decimals=3)*array - 6` 3 decimals points is the limit of accuracy in my dataset. to check if there is no remainder i did `np.isclose(np.round(6/array, decimals=3)*array - 6, 0)`

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti that's more or less what I'd have done :) Since MATLAB is the one doing something weird you have to mess with something like `isclose` to reproduce their behaviour. At least the 3 decimal precision you have makes this fairly robust, which would've been my main concern.

Comment: Thanks again, I believe, developers at `numpy` should not make the statement that their `mod` function is equivalent to Matlab's `mod` function.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti the exact wording is "_The MATLAB function equivalent to np.remainder is mod_" which doesn't explicitly claim that they are exactly the same (i.e. returning the exact same output for the same input), but I can see how it's suggestive of that. One's mileage of "equivalent" may vary. You can raise this as [an issue with numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) and it might be changed (not the behaviour, but the phrasing in the docs).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround. It basically rounds the denominator to its str representation and from there does integer arithmetic:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal

def round_divmod(b,a):
     n,d = np.frompyfunc(lambda x:decimal.Decimal(x).as_integer_ratio(),1,2)(a.astype('U'))
     n,d = n.astype(int),d.astype(int)
     q,r = np.divmod(b*d,n)
     return q,r/d

a = np.round(np.linspace(0.05,1,20),2).reshape(4,5)
a
# array([[0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.25],
#        [0.3 , 0.35, 0.4 , 0.45, 0.5 ],
#        [0.55, 0.6 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.75],
#        [0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 1.  ]])
round_divmod(6,a)
# (array([[120,  60,  40,  30,  24],
#        [ 20,  17,  15,  13,  12],
#        [ 10,  10,   9,   8,   8],
#        [  7,   7,   6,   6,   6]]), array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
#        [0.  , 0.05, 0.  , 0.15, 0.  ],
#        [0.5 , 0.  , 0.15, 0.4 , 0.  ],
#        [0.4 , 0.05, 0.6 , 0.3 , 0.  ]]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed it works like a charm. but i found rounding the numbers is easier and faster operation as suggested by @Andras Deak